# How to save in wp_options table as WordPress standards?

Tags: wordpress

I have a form it sends data to options.php. After that that saved value takes and imported into textarea.

```
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php

         settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );
         do_settings_sections( 'my_settings_admin' );
         submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
```

This code works, but if I want to save in DB some default value manually, the value doesn't come into textarea's value. I'm using `add_option` or `update_option`.

Answer (score 0):

Understand this flow to save the value to database,

```
/* code for adding menu and options in admin */

add_action('admin_menu','admin_menu_adding');
add_action('admin_init','admin_reg_settings');

function admin_menu_adding(){
    add_menu_page('Mega Page','Mega Page','administrator','mega-page','settings_page_test');
}

function settings_page_test(){
    echo "test";
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php'); ?>">
        <?php
        settings_fields('local-settings');
        do_settings_sections('local-settings');
        ?>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="trotbgo" />
    </form>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_action_trotbgo','save_value_here');

function save_value_here(){
    update_option() //update option goes here
    exit;
}

function admin_reg_settings(){
    register_setting('local-settings','fieldone');
    register_setting('local-settings','fieldtwo');
}
```

You need to save via the `add_option/update_option` inside `save_value_here()` function